# Android OpenGL error during Camera animation

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es

I found the following code that I use to flip two CardViews containing a chart (I use MPAndroidCharts lib), creating a 3D card flip effect:

```
public class FlipAnimation extends Animation {

...

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    // Angle around the y-axis of the rotation at the given time
    // calculated both in radians and degrees.
    final double radians = Math.PI * interpolatedTime;
    float degrees = (float) (180.0 * radians / Math.PI);

    // Once we reach the midpoint in the animation, we need to hide the
    // source view and show the destination view. We also need to change
    // the angle by 180 degrees so that the destination does not come in
    // flipped around
    if (interpolatedTime >= 0.5f) {
        degrees -= 180.f;
        fromView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (forward)
        degrees = -degrees; //determines direction of rotation when flip begins

    final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();
    camera.save();
    if(horizontal){
        camera.rotateX(degrees);
    } else {
        camera.rotateY(degrees);
    }
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();
    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
}
```

The original code was only able to flip along the vertical center axis, so I added that little `if` when a boolean is set, then the animation is made along the horizontal center axis. Now sometimes during the animation, the following weird error crashes my app:

```
03-20 16:37:26.369 551-579/c.f.q.android.demo A/OpenGLRenderer: Error: Spot pair overflow!!! used 30, total 22
03-20 16:37:26.370 551-579/c.f.q.android.demo A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 579 (hwuiTask1)
```

It seems that this error only happens when I rotate along the horizontal axis, but even this case, the error does not happen consistently (e.g. sometimes it works countless times and sometimes it crashes on the second flip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your card view need a shadow ? I was able to fix my error by setting  elevation of CardView to 0dp. So in xml :-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

Some other open source projects were also seeing this error :- https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar/issues/73 .

Comment: Yes, I do have shadow on it. Thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this seems to resolve the issue! :)
Anyway, do you have any idea how can I "emulate" elevation shadow now?